# RegEx searching whole words ending or beginning with special symbols

Tags: c#, regex, web-services

I am trying to do a search in a file which may include a # and have tried the following two RegEx statements, and neither work. Can someone show me the correct RegEx that I can search for regular alphanumeric characters and also if the user includes a # or another special character?

Using NLog, I can see that the string is correctly sent to the web service. And then I build the following RegEx (tried 2 different ways).

```
\b(?:C#)\b
\b(?:C\#)\b
```

Here is a partial string from my file that you see contains the string I'm searching for:

```
by multiple customers C# both external and internal
```

C# Code:

```
var reader = File.ReadAllText(currentFile);

var pattern = @"\b(?:" + searchPhrases[0] + @")\b"; \\ I've tried escaping it also.

// Works for a word like this ("White Paper" or "Paper" but not for "C# White Paper")
if (Regex.IsMatch(reader, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
    searchResults.AppendLine(currentFile);

    searchResults.Append("|");
}
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "searchservice.asmx/SearchFiles",
    data: { searchParameters: parameters, searchOnCompletePhrase: completePhrase },
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "text",
    contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        processSearchData(data);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        lookupErrorDefinition(this);

        console.log(XMLHttpRequest.status);
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you can use `@"(?<!\w)(?:" + Regex.Escape(searchPhrases[0]) + @")(?!\w)"`. Also, whitespace boundaries are "popular": `@"(?<!\S)(?:" + Regex.Escape(searchPhrases[0]) + @")(?!\S)"`

Comment: I tried that and it works great from a console app calling the web service. When I call the service from a Ajax call, it does not work. I've included the Ajax call so you can see it. Words without special characters work in both the web and the console.

Comment: Do you mean you are using JavaScript regex engine? You will need to replace `(?<!\w)` with `(?:^|\W)` and `(?<!\S)` with `(?:^|\s)`

Comment: I'm using C# RegEx on the web service side.

Comment: Then my regexes from top comment should work.

Comment: It works when I test the web service from a console app (both in Visual Studio). But when I deploy the service and call it from a web page, it does not work. I've checked that the parameters are being passed correctly to the service. Is there anything on the web side that I should look at?

Comment: That part is not related to regex, sorry.

Comment: Your RegEx works great. I had a JavaScript error that kept my results from showing. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Please consider upvoting my solution if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the two solutions:

```
 var pattern = @"(?<!\w)(?:" + Regex.Escape(searchPhrases[0]) + @")(?!\w)";
```

Or

```
var pattern = @"(?<!\S)(?:" + Regex.Escape(searchPhrases[0]) + @")(?!\S)";
```

In the first solution, `(?<!\w)` matches a location that is not preceded with a word char, and `(?!\w)` matches a location that is not followed with a word char.

In the second solution, `(?<!\S)` matches a location that is not preceded with a non-whitespace char (i.e. is preceded with whitespace or start of string), and `(?!\S)` matches a location that is not followed with a non-whitespace char (i.e. is followed with a whitespace char or end of string).